# TMs can decide whether or not a string is a Palindrome, yet, the language called PALINDROMES is undecidable - why?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, decidability

I came across this language, where M denotes a Turing Machine:

[PALINDROMES](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Elyuu/complexity/2017/20171024s.pdf) $:= \{M \mid M \text{ accepts strings which are palindromes}\}.$ It is proven to undecidable.

And, I know one can construct a Turing Machine that decides for strings, if they are palindromes or not.

Further, a set A is decidable if and only if there exists a computable function $f(x) : Σ^* \to \{0, 1\}$ such that for any input $x \in Σ^*$, $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is in $A$, and $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is not in $A$.

In other words:

$$A \text{ is decidable } \Leftrightarrow \exists f(x) : Σ^* \to \{0, 1\}\text{, where }f(x)\text{ is computable and}$$

$$f(x) = 1\text{ if }x \in A\ ,$$

$$f(x) = 0\text{ if }x \not\in A\ .$$

How come then, that the existence of a TM that decides whether or not a given string is a palindrome is not sufficient condition to say, that the language PALINDROMES decidable?

Basically, i try to make out the source of my confusion. Do I confuse the "language of palindromes" and "the language of Turing machines that accept palindromes"(PALINDROMES)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, you are confusing the two languages.

You know that, via "gödelization", you can associate to every Turing machine $M$ a number $\lceil M \rceil$ in bijective way (this can be done in multiple way, but you can fix one of this way, for example using a binary alphabet and fixing the rules coherently).

Consider the machine $M$ that recognize the set of palindromes: what can you say about its Gödel number $\lceil M \rceil$? Probably not much; for sure there is no reason for this number to be a palindrome in base 2.

The fact that the set PALINDROMES is not decidable, while the set of binary palindrome strings is, has this implication: there's no gödelization such that a Turing machine recognizes the set of binary palindrome if and only if its Gödel number is a palindrome.

Another example: the set of even number is recognizable, while the set of Turing machine that recognize all the even numbers is not: this implies that, for every gödelization, there are two Turing machine $M$ and $M'$ that recognize the set of even numbers such that $\lceil M \rceil$ is even and $\lceil M' \rceil$ is odd.